# Validate email AngularJS in Controller

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, validation, email

I have a list of inputs where the use can type in emails, and in these inputs I want to allow invaild inputs so on the input tag I have `ng-model-options="{allowInvalid: true}"` and then when the user is done typing in all there emails, they hit a submit button which calls my function `enter()` in the controller.

In the HTML I have set each email input with `ng-model="item.text"` so then in the controller I can loop through my emails. This is where I want to check if they are valid or not. How can I do this?

I saw on https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/input/input%5Bemail%5D the `myForm.input.$valid` is used so I got all the input elements and tried `inputEle.$valid` but this always comes back as `undefined`.

So in my loop I have access to both the raw text the user put in such as:

```
test@@email..com
vaild@email.com
```

And I have access to the input element like

```
<input type="email" placeholder="Email" ng-model="item.text" ng-model-options="{allowInvalid: true}" class="ng-not-empty ng-dirty ng-invalid ng-invalid-email ng-invalid-remove ng-valid-email-add ng-invalid-email-remove ng-touched" style="">
```

So how in that loop in my controller can I validate the email?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

In order to inspect the input in the controller you have to set the "name" attribute in it. For example:

```
<input type="email" name="email_name" placeholder="Email" ng-model="item.text" ng-model-options="{allowInvalid: true}" class="ng-not-empty ng-dirty ng-invalid ng-invalid-email ng-invalid-remove ng-valid-email-add ng-invalid-email-remove ng-touched" style="">
```

And then in the controller you access to $valid property:

```
...
if(myForm.email_name.$valid) {
  ...
}
...
```

Example: https://jsfiddle.net/vk94weuu/2/

Comment: Okay so if I have a list of inputs all with the same name, for example "email_name" and I get them like this `var emails = document.getElementsByName('email_name')` and then loop though `emails` so in each iteration I have `email` will I be able to do `if (email.$valid)`?

Comment: I don't think it's a good idea to name two or more inputs the same in the same form. Though it's ok in different forms. If the number of inputs is constant, then name them differently. If not, then you can try this approach: https://jsfiddle.net/vk94weuu/4/